# Taping an android home-screen widget doesn't work the second time

Tags: java, android, widget

I am new to Android(started yesterday :))
I am trying to make a simple home-screen widget with a TextView that changes it's value when you tap on it.
Things aren't going so well. It only works after I tap it 3 times and then it works once and never works again. Also the debugger always crashes after I "step over" for the first time.

Manifest:

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <receiver android:name=".GeeDeeBeeDee"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CLICK" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/gee_dee_bee_dee_info" />
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Widget class:

```
public class GeeDeeBeeDee extends AppWidgetProvider {

private int DayType = 0;

public static String APPWIDGET_CLICK = "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CLICK";

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds[i]);
```

and then:

```
    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int appWidgetId)
{
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.gee_dee_bee_dee);

    Intent intent = new Intent(APPWIDGET_CLICK);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, appWidgetId, intent, 0);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.appwidget_text, pendingIntent );

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    int widgetId = 0;

    if (APPWIDGET_CLICK.equals(intent.getAction()))
    {

        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.gee_dee_bee_dee);

        if(DayType == 0)
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, "0");
        else if(DayType == 1)
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, "1");
        else if(DayType == 2)
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, "2");

        if(DayType > 2)
            DayType = 0;

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if(extras!=null)
        {
            widgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        }

        if(widgetId > 0)
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
    }
    else
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
```

Can anyone help, please? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is in your `onUpdate()` method. You may want to check this link: [Android: How to update widget text on creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29359403/android-how-to-update-widget-text-on-creation/29362921#29362921)

I hope it will help you.