# Android widget exit from Configuration

Tags: android, android-activity, widget, configure, provider

I am creating a widget with a configuration activity, and I was wondering how do I exit the configuration and update the widget according to the settings the user entered? Is there n android default or do I have to manually create a button to exit? I have the following code right now:

Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".WidgetConfigure">
       <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE"/>
       </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Widget:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="250dp"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/widget_icon"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
    android:configure="com.example.widget.WidgetConfigure"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen|keyguard">

</appwidget-provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

look at this link to update your widget on creation: [Android: How to update widget text on creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29359403/android-how-to-update-widget-text-on-creation/29362921#29362921)

And after you've done editing Configure Activity, try update your widget with this method in Configure Activity:

```
 private void updateWidgetScreen(String updateData) {

        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(this, WidgetProvider.class);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.kalanPara, updateData);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WidgetService.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, MainUtils.getWidgetID(prefs));
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(MainUtils.getWidgetID(prefs), R.id.list_view, intent);

        Intent clickIntent = new Intent(this, ConfigureActivity.class);
        PendingIntent clickPI = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        remoteViews.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.list_view, clickPI);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
    }
```

Then you can simply exit activity with this code: (but it's not necessary)

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }
```